# Sorting with condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Here is the example collection:

```
[
 {'name': 'element1', ratings: {'user1': 1, 'user2':2}},
 {'name': 'element2', ratings: {'user1': 2, 'user2':1}}
]
```

I want to sort for user1:  ['element2', 'element1'] ,
and for user2: ['element1', 'element2'].

In other words, I want to place the results with maximum rating for current user to top.

The collection is very big, thats why search must use indexes. The collection structure can be modified, this is just example.

Comment: Aggregation wramework can help, but I dont know how to use it for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Those are sorts on different fields. The first is a sort on `{ "ratings.user1" : -1 }` and the second is a sort on `{ "ratings.user2" : -1 }`; you will need an index on each field to support each sort. You can't scale a set up like that beyond a few users. I don't know what the entire use case is for these documents, but if the core requirement is to sort elements for a user based on the user's ratings, I would restructure the collection so that a single document represents a rating of a particular element by a particular user:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(...),
    "element" : "element1",
    "user" : "user1",
    "rating" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(...),
    "element" : "element1",
    "user" : "user2",
    "rating" : 2
}
```

If you create an index on `{ "user" : 1, "rating" : -1 }`, you can perform indexed queries for the ratings of elements by a particular user sorted descending by rating:

```
db.ratings.find({ "user" : "user1" }).sort({ "rating" : -1 })
```

Comment: "Sorts on different fields" -  this is good, but creating an index for each user is not good.  If only I could create the index on entire "ratings".  The second way is for joins, but mongodb doesnt have them. The big result with pagination, how can I sort it?

Comment: And the second way doesnt solve the problem. Because I want to find all results, not only for user1 (but sorting for user1).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand either of your comments. Second way? How do joins come in? What do you mean "find all results, not only for user1"? You want to find all elements and sort on user1's rating, even if user1 hasn't rated an element?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.  I have millions of documents in main collection and thousands of users.   The join come in because of separate ratings collection. But there is no need for it, because I can use subdocument. `{name: 'element1', ratings: [{user: 'user1', rating: 1}, {user: 'user2', rating:2} ]}`  But how can I **sort** by user1 ratings (not find)?

Comment: I still don't think I understand. The document structure and query I showed you does sort by user1 ratings. You can't do the sort you want with all of the ratings stuffed in an array like that - how would you express the sort key?

Comment: The same as you - sort with find. I will show you what is the problem with find. Main collection (million records): `[{id: 'el1'}, {id: 'el2'}, ... ]` The ratings collection:`[{element: 'el1', user:'user1', rating: 1}, {{element: 'el1', user:'user2', rating: 2}, ...]` The query with pagination: `db.main.find(any_query).skip(0).limit(50)` Your solution: `db.main.find(any_query); //can be million records`  and another query to ratings: `db.ratings.find({ "user" : "user1" }).sort({ "rating" : -1 })`  later the program combines first and second query and takes 50 first records (very slow).